# How to disable help pop ups in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

[image]

Been trying to figure out ways on how to remove this popup which I do not need and find annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion.
Then, UNCHECK the box that says "Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc."

Comment: Nah... more like the check box just above it: `Show suggestions as you type` -- to disable such popup from auto appearing (you can still call it with `Ctrl+Space` or whatever the shortcut is on your OS/kaymap). The one you have mentioned ("Insert selected suggestion by pressing space, dot, or other context-dependent keys") is about actually inserting the selected entry in that popup.